# What is $a & $b and $a | $b in php?

Tags: php

What happend $a & $b and $a | $b in php ?

```
$a = 11;
$b = 7;
echo $a & $b;
```

In the above php code it will give result 3 How it will calculate 3 ?

```
$a = 11;
$b = 7;
echo $a | $b;
```

In the above php code it will give result 15 How it will calculate 15?

Explain me both condition in php?

Comment: Those are [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: ya thanx for your response , how it's calculation done using bitwise operator?

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is something called [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It's more often used in much lower level languages, and it's one of the very simplest things a computer can do. Most computation is built on top of it. So what is it? Well, `&` is the `Bitwise AND` operator, and `|` is the `Bitwise OR` operator. You can test them with [this online tool](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator). But let's breakdown how it works.

#### AND Operator

Take two binary strings and any `1`'s that aren't in *both* binaries, the the same place, become a `0`.

`7` is `111`
`11` is `1011`

So if you perform an `AND` on them, you get something like this

```
0111 &
1011 =
0011
```

`0011` in Decimal is `3`. You get `0011` because only the last two places are BOTH `1`.

#### OR Operator

`OR` is basically the opsite. If a position in *either* binary is `1`, then the output is `1`. So when you perform it on `7` and `11`, you'll get

```
1011 |
0111 =
1111
```

And `1111` is `15` in decimal

Answer (score 2):

In binary, `11` is `00001011` and `7` is `00000111` (showing only relevant 8 bits for simplicity).

---

So `11 & 7` (bitwise AND)

```
00001011
00000111 & matching only where both matching bits are `1`
--------
00000011
```

which is the binary for `3`

---

So `11 | 7` (bitwise OR)

```
00001011
00000111 | matching where either (or both) bits is `1`
--------
00001111
```

which is the binary for `15`